# Can't align text left in table due to pre-existing style on Wordpress site but can't find it with firebug

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'd like to align the text in the "Features" column left. However I am unable due to some preexisting style.

[This is the page](http://leadrabbit.com/pricing/) I'm referring to.

Comment: Modify the `#ethernatable th.tablecol, #ethernatable td.tableid, #ethernatable td.even, #ethernatable td.odd rule` in http://leadrabbit.com/wp-content/themes/ETHERNA_WP1/css/style.css

Comment: it appears that the `<td>`s have inline styling: `<td align="center" class="even last">` That will override pretty much everything.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in `style.css` for `#ethernatable td.tableid`. I'm seeing a `text-align: center;` being applied by that rule using Google Chrome's Developer Tools.

**Edit:**

Removing the rule using the Developer Tools makes the whole column left-justified as you specify. You'll either need to edit the style or override the styling with another one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

it's being inherited from:

`#ethernatable th.tablecol, #ethernatable td.tableid, #ethernatable td.even, #ethernatable td.odd`

You can override it by adding to this:

`#ethernatable td h6`